# How to make a Custom field to be Editable from Experience Editor in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sxa, experience-editor

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7. We have a requirement for video component with some extra fields so I have cloned the existing video component and added a custom field for it and I want to show that custom field in the Experience Editor like MovieCaption and MovieDescription which is shown in existing SXA video component.

I want to show my custom field along with those 2 text editor options.

[image]

Can anyone please help how can i achieve that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on the original View for OOTB Video component located under `$path_to_sitecore_instance$\Views\Video\Video.cshtml`:

[image]

Copy those 3 highlighted lines either for Caption or Description fields:

```
<div class="video-caption">
                @Html.Sxa().Field("MovieCaption", Model.DataSourceItem, Model.GetRenderingWebEditingParams())
            </div>
```

Change the definition of which field to change:
`@Html.Sxa().Field("MovieCaption", Model.DataSourceItem, Model.GetRenderingWebEditingParams())` to your desired by replacing "MovieCaption" with "My-custom-field-name"

Don't forget not to do this in OOTB Video View cshtml file. But create your own by copying the original cshtml file, make above changes and then set Rendering View Path on your custom Video component (cloned from OOTB one):

[image]