# Unable to make Visual studio model fields editable in experience editor for Sitecore SXA

Tags: sxa, experience-editor, visual-studio

I'm using a custom `Sitecore SXA` controller rendering for the first time with `Visual Studio` and I want to make the model fields in the `.cshtml` view file editable in `Sitecore Experience editor`. Is there a way to go about this? Referred to the following link for custom  rendering in `SXA`

[Simple SXA rendering](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/walkthrough--building-a-simple-rendering.html)

[image]

I tried the following method with the help of [how to make a custom field to be editable from experience editor in sitecore 9.0.1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/28456/how-to-make-a-custom-field-to-be-editable-from-experience-editor-in-sitecore-9-0); however it doesn't work.

[image]

**Specification details:**

```
Sitecore 10.2,
Visual Studio 2022
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use EditFrame in your view like this ?

```
     using (Html.Sxa().BeginEditFrame(Html.Sitecore().CurrentRendering.DataSource, "Image Slider Empty", Model.IsControlEditable))
 {
     @Model.MessageIsEmpty
 }
```

please find EditFrames documentation : https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/91/sitecore-experience-manager/using-editframes.html

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes I tried this the field content is getting selected in experience editor but I am unable to edit it. It gets highlighted as Page area and displays no workflow.